# Contradictory PDP plots

Tags: machine-learning

Let's say we have two models: one is a random forest, and the other one is a xgboost model. Those two models yield similar accuracies but in the PDP plots, one model says features A, B, C have a relatively strong positive impact on the label, whereas the other model says the exact opposite (strong negative impact). In that case, what should we do? Should I be concerned and find out which model is more sane?

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but I wouldn't put too much faith into PDP plots. Two issues I see are: (i) PDP plots make very strong independence assumptions which may be violated by your data (ii) in tree-based models you should be factoring in how often A,B,C are split on. What if variable A is split on in only 1 tree in each model? -- your PDP plots are going to be highly sensitive to the randomness of these trees. Since you're using tree-based models I would put more faith in (tree-based) feature-importance, which factor in split frequency, rather than PDP plots.

Comment: It always depends on what is your exact *objective* from your analysis. Keep in mind that PDP plots, like other interpretability methods, do not claim to offer *causal* interpretations.

Comment: Should not happen. At most a flat plot. Could you please add more details e.g. FI and plot screen for both the Model? Looks very interesting.